# Pop Easy Modal: Activating Modal on Page Load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm trying to get the Pop Easy modal to activate on pageload but I can't even get it to work on the demo file included.

Here is the part thats suppose to make it open on page load:

`openOnLoad: true              // open modal on page load | true or false | default=false`

and here is the demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YmrvZ/). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: find a better plugin or even better : make the plugin yourself to suit your need (instead of adapting your needs to the plugin !)

Comment: @mikakun i wouldnt know how to create one myself.. would it not be easier to get this to work instead of switching my code to a diff plugin?

Comment: plugin needs full rewrite as it's using functions that have been deprecated by latest jquery